# How does this work? What exactly is happening?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin and I know the basics of C#. One of the first codes I encounter is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Hello
{
    public class App : Application
    {
    public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }
        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

The part where I have a problem is

```
Children = {
    new Label {
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
}
```

I don't understand what's happening here. What is `Children`? What is it getting assigned to?

Comment: Children is a property of StackLayout

Comment: To be even more exact, it's an inherited property from [`Layout<T>`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Layout%3CT%3E.Children/)

Comment: this link gives you good idea https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout/

Comment: And if you are confused by the braces you should read up on [Object and Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`Children` is not assigned to, but `Children` is *initialized*. It is more confusing as property `Children' is not browsable, so it does not appear in intellisense.

`Children` is `IList<View>`.

You can initialize collection like this...

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{
     "s1",
     "s2",
     "s3"
};
```

which is equivalent to

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("s1");
list.Add("s2");
list.Add("s3");
```

Similarly

```
Children = {
    new Label{
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Children.Add(new Label{  });
```

However, there is no official document about how to initialize collection property like this, but it seems compiler converts expression cleverly. I tried to compile and it seems it did work correctly.

You can see an example here, https://dotnetfiddle.net/8jln93

Comment: For official documentation, see the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) in UnholySheep's comment.

Comment: And how does the stuff inside the braces work? The `new Label {
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }`

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Official document mentions how to create new object with initializer, but not how to initialize an `IList` property which is readonly, note it is not `Children = new ... {` , but it is `Children={`

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya, Simple, each left side of assignment is property which is initialized to value at right side of the assignment.